# Make an exact replica of a view (excluding data) in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to make an exact replica of a View in Google Analytics?

Based on the documentation here (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3256366?hl=en&fbclid=IwAR2_5523Iz89Be8P6wkXxMla5BiS9NL4DLrzVuJ1ib23WvuDwzq4idnGBa4).

> Settings and features controlled at the view level (like filters,
> Goals, users and their permissions) are duplicated in copied views.
> Cost source links and shared assets (like annotations, Segments, and
> alerts) are not duplicated into copied views.

It seems like many items don't get copied across. I also noted that `calculated metrics` and `custom reports` are also not copied across.

Is there a way to create an exact replica (excluding the data)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related but rather related to the web app Google analytics may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Management API to get/create some setting, like segments (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/segments?hl=it) and create a feature that automatically creates a view with the desired settings, custom report can be shared, ... however there are some settings that cannot be created in this way either, for example annotations API is not available.